# reached end of file while parsing,

Tags: file, parsing

what is wrong with this , i am getting an error that states: reached end of file while parsing. what do i do to fix this?
i have tried several thing with no result

```
public class FindMin
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int smallest = 9999999;
    String userInput;
    boolean quit = false;

    System.out.println("This program finds the smallest number"
        + " in a series of numbers");
    System.out.println("When you want to exit, type Q");

    while(quit != true)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        userInput = keyboard.next();
        if(userInput.equals("Q")) userInput.equals("q");
        {
            if(quit == true) {

}

           else            

          { 

             int userNumber = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

            if(UserNumber < smallest)
                smallest = userNumber;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The smallest number is " + smallest);
    System.exit(0);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was just too messy, try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FindMin{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int smallest = 9999999;
    String userInput;
    boolean quit = false;

    System.out.println("This program finds the smallest number"
        + " in a series of numbers");
    System.out.println("When you want to exit, type Q");

    while(true)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        userInput = keyboard.next();
        if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
                break;
        else{
            int userNumber = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
            if(userNumber < smallest)
                smallest = userNumber;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The smallest number is " + smallest);
}
}
```

Comment: You sure you are using the latest version? just copy the whole block and replace your main block again

I just tried, here is the output

`This program finds the smallest number in a series of numbers
When you want to exit, type Q
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: 6
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 7
Enter a number: q
The smallest number is 4`

Comment: yeah, i cant get it to run

Comment: Pretty sure you didn't copy it right, i just updated again, this time copy & replace EVERYTHING in your java file and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Check your braces: they don't match up, which is why the compiler complains:

```
FindMin.java:35: reached end of file while parsing
```

Besides there's a typo and some other issues with that program. See other answers for reference :)